# Getting IllegalBlockSize when trying to encrypt too much data

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption

Here are my constants

```
//Encryption fields
/** Algorithm=RSA Mode=ECB Padding=PKCS1Padding*/
public static final String ALGORITHM_MODE_PADDING = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
/** Algorithm=RSA */
public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
/** Provider=BouncyCastle */
public static final String PROVIDER = "BC";
/** Key size for the public and private keys */
public static final int KEY_SIZE = 1024;
```

I have made two public / private keys like this:

```
//Generate the keys
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM,PROVIDER);
kpg.initialize(KEY_SIZE);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pubk = kp.getPublic();
PrivateKey prvk = kp.getPrivate();
```

I am decrypting like this:

```
byte[] privateKey = Base64.decodeBase64(pKey); //decode
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM,PROVIDER);
PrivateKey privKey = factory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_MODE_PADDING);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);
return cipher.doFinal(data);
```

This works with small amounts of data, when when the data becomes larger such as **263 bytes** if fails with an IllegalBlockSizeException.  I thinks this is because the data is greater than 256 bytes but that is just an guess and I have no idea of how to fix it.

What am I doing wrong?

I changed it to use the update method, but still have the same problem:

```
// encryption pass
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);
byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
int ctLength = cipher.update(data, 0, data.length, cipherText, 0);
ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
```

I am trying to implement digital signatures by the way.  The client has the public key and the server has the private key.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you mean to encrypt data and you are using RSA, why do you use private key for encryption?

Comment: @krystian so what should I be using as opposed to RSA?  The encryption and descyption are done at separate times on different devices

Comment: @jax: if you want to encrypt using RSA, use the public key of the receiver

Comment: @if you want to implement digital signatures, who is going to sign the messages? The server? - you mentioned it has the private key. Remember that to sign, you need to use the private key.

Comment: yes the server has the private key, the public key is stored on the client.  I managed to get rid of this IllegalBlockSize problem.

Comment: I a have another Thread on the best way to implemnt this Hybrid aproach if you want to comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171392/recommended-encryption-combination-for-digital-signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use RSA to encrypt more data than the size in bytes of the modulus - 11. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Just curious: if you didn't want to bother with the hybrid method, would you just break your data down into sections of a small block size and encrypt sequentially?  If that makes sense, how do you determine the block size?

Comment: That would of course get rid of the errors. block size = modulus_size - 11, where modulus size = (modulus.bitLength() + 7) / 8.

Comment: +1 Hybrid encryption is the correct solution because symmetric ciphers are much faster, you wouldn't want to encrypt large chunks of data using only RSA - that would slow down the system a lot.

Comment: I missed that you are trying to implement digital signatures. To do so, just use the Signature class.